# How to manually install PostgreSql on Redhat

Tags: postgresql, installation, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have to install PostgreSql onto Redhat.
I cannot use YUM.
I have downloaded these rpm's



`postgresql91-9.1.9-1PGDG.rhel5.x86_64.rpm

postgresql91-contrib-9.1.9-1PGDG.rhel5.x86_64.rpm

postgresql91-libs-9.1.9-1PGDG.rhel5.x86_64.rpm

postgresql91-server-9.1.9-1PGDG.rhel5.x86_64.rpm`


What i need to know...
a). Is this all i require?
b). Is there a "correct" sequence to "rpm -ivh" these?

Comment: Shouldn't you compile it from source, if `yum` is not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `rpm -Uvh postgresql91-*.rpm`. It will install it in correct order and it will complain if it needs something.

But I can't imagine why you can't use `yum`.

Comment: i do like to see simple answers. we cannot use YUM as our target servers do not have internet access.

Comment: Why wouldn't a user be able to use yum? Maybe they are running a private server inside an enterprise environment. Maybe they have a local machine without proxy authorization. Maybe they have a department intranet. Maybe they are trying to prove something.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add in postgresql91-devel.x86_64 as well. 
Also, is there a reason to choose 9.1 over 9.2?

There are some RPM steps on the postgresql wiki: [RPM_Installation](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/RPM_Installation)